# PurchReqApproval Workflow stopped working

Tags: axapta, sharepoint-workflow, ax, workflowservice

PurchReqApproval workflow stopped working, that is all the workflow's messages are in pending state. There were no modifications made to objects related to that workflow (maybe except EDTs). 
I am thinking this issue might be consequence of changing server admin password. Any hints how and where can I check/fix outdated password in IIS/AX/Services?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to your IIS manager and then click on application pools.  Find the relevant one and right click on it and do advanced settings, then look at its identity (username) and click the ellipse `...`.  Try setting the password again and recycling the app pool and/or doing an `iisreset`.